# Telling Google that example.com and example.us points to the same site

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, multiple-domains

example.com - global domain

example.us - geo-local domain

1. Tell me how should I let Google Webmaster Tools and Google Analytics know that the site has more than one domain?
2. Does having more than one domain, corrupt SEO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### SEO and Webmaster Tools

You have a couple options.  Either of these can work from an SEO perspective.

1. Pick one of them and use that as the "canonical" domain.

   1. Use 301 redirects to make sure that visitors all get to the one you choose.
   2. OR use the [rel canonical meta tag](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) to tell Google which domain is the preferred domain (while letting users access whichever they want).
2. OR Use the `.us` domain for traffic from the United States, and use the `.com` for traffic from the rest of the world.

   1. Add both domains in [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).  Use the "Geographic target" feature under ["configuration" -> "settings"](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/settings) to set the `.us` domain to "US" and the `.com` domain to global.
   2. Redirect users between the sites based on geo-ip-address.

### Google Analytics

If you choose to have multiple top level domains where users can view content, there is a setting for multiple top level domains in analytics.  Use the "Admin" feature and make sure you are in the correct "account" and "property".  In the "property" settings there "tracking info" tab.  In that tab, there is a setting for "Multiple top-level domains of <site>".  Flipping that switch will slightly alter the analytics tracking javascript code that gets embedded on your site.  Re-install this new analytics code onto your site.

Comment: "Multiple top-level domains" no longer seems to be an option in Google Analytics, or at least I can't find it.

Comment: There used to be radio buttons for generating a tracking snippet with it built in.   You can still do it, but you have to add pieces to the tracking snippet yourself.   This document shows you how: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en